# The type arguments for method cannot be inferred from the usage.Try specifying the type arguments explicitly

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, visual-studio, html-helper

The error is :The type arguments for method 'System.Web.Mvc.Html.ValidationExtensions.ValidationMessageFor..........' cannot be inferred from the usage.Try specifying the type arguments explicitly.

```
      <div class="form-group">
      <label for="email">Email address</label>
      <input type="email" class="form-control" id="email" aria- 
      describedby="emailHelp">
      <small id="emailHelp" class="form-text text-muted">We'll never share 
       your email with anyone else.</small>
       <label class="text-danger">@Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => 
       model.Email)</label>
       </div>
```

Comment: Does your `*.cshtml` file have a `@model TypeNameGoesHere` statement? What is the full type-name of `this.Html`? Does your View-Model type have a property named `Email`?

Comment: Yes, the *.cshtml file has the statement @model TimeTracking.Models.login . The name of the Html file is index.cshtml . And the code in the model is : public partial class login
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        [Required(ErrorMessage ="This field is required")] 
        public string Email { get; set; }
        [Required(ErrorMessage = "This field is required")]
        public string password { get; set; }
        public String LoginErrorMessage { get; set; }
    }

Comment: Clean and Rebuild your project and maybe restart Visual Studio, it could be a caching issue.

Comment: Done it multiple times.No progress.

Comment: What are the type arguments and how can we specify them explicitly?